# I found Polyfill for IE To support Array.from . How do i include in my html?

Tags: internet-explorer, polyfills

Here is the polyfill Location :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Polyfill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in a `<script>` tag before the JavaScript that uses that feature. The polyfill is simply JavaScript that modifies the `Array.prototype` object so that arrays have the new feature, and it needs to run before code that expects that feature to be there.

Comment: Thank You ... So this should be included at the start of the html file right... will include in <script> accordingly